# Show next image from div when click button

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

In a few words - I display posts inside WP Google Map Pro that allows to list posts. Therefore I cannot use any gallery that needs shortcode because plugin doesn't display shortcodes.

I tried to create my own gallery based on pictures. Here is what it looks like more or less - this is sample:

```
<div id="post_content">
<img src="image1.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="image2.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="image3.jpg" class="thumb" />
</div>

<div class="showimagediv"></div>
```

I use jquery to do that and it works fine:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumb').on('click', function() {
        var img = $('<img />', {src    : this.src,
                                'class': 'fullImage'
                  });

        $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();
    });

        $('.showimagediv').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

However, I can only show image and close it. But I wanted to make it look like lightbox with arrowx PREV NEXT.

The question is:
How can I do that? To load next image from the same div into the div "showimagediv" and replace image1 with image2? Is there any solution?

Comment: You mean gallery image clicking prev and next button?

Comment: Yes. But I need to do it with the same method. Remember, cannot use gallery with shortcode...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".showimagediv").html($("img").eq(0).clone())
    var pos = 0;
    $('#prev').on('click', function() {
        if(pos>0) pos--
          $(".showimagediv").hide().html($("img").eq(pos).clone()).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('#next').on('click', function() {
        if(pos<2) pos++
        $(".showimagediv").hide().html($("img").eq(pos).clone()).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    
    $('.showimagediv').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.img1{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
.img2{
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
}
.img3{
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post_content">
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66" class="thumb img1" />
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66" class="thumb img2" />
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66" class="thumb img3" />
</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button><br><br>
<span></span>
<div class="showimagediv"></div>
```

Comment: There is a problem with that. Because I have images in many different divs. Like that: `<div class="post_content">
<img src="image1.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="image2.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="image3.jpg" class="thumb" />
</div><div class="post_content">
<img src="image4.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="image5.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="image6.jpg" class="thumb" />
</div>`     And so on. Have a [link](http://polenbegeisterungswelle.com/testowa-agenda/)

Comment: And I need to load into "showimagediv" imgage3 when click on that, then load image5 there. Is that possible? When I did your code, it didn't work there...