# How to change the displayed image on a quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to create a quiz about movies using HTML, CSS and JS. I'm a beginner with all of them. So far I was doing good without running in any issues, I followed a guy's guide to create the script for the quiz: [Quiz creation of JS](https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/).

Then, I ran into an issue, I want the 3 questions to show different screenshots from movies to make the user guess which movie it is from, but I have no idea about how to show the image in the quiz and make it change after the event of "Next Question" being pressed.

I've been trying to solve it following this previous answer to a similar question with no results. [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683940/show-next-image-from-div-when-click-button)

Here I have the script:

```
    (function(){
    // Functions
    function buildQuiz(){
      // variable to store the HTML output
      const output = [];
  
      // for each question...
      myQuestions.forEach(
        (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
  
          // variable to store the list of possible answers
          const answers = [];
  
          // and for each available answer...
          for(letter in currentQuestion.answers){
  
            // ...add an HTML radio button
            answers.push(
              `<label>
                <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
                ${letter} :
                ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
              </label>`
            );
          }
  
          // add this question and its answers to the output
          output.push(
            `<div class="slide">
              <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
            </div>`
          );
        }
      );
  
      // finally combine our output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
      quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
    }
  
    function showResults(){
  
      // gather answer containers from our quiz
      const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');
  
      // keep track of user's answers
      let numCorrect = 0;
  
      // for each question...
      myQuestions.forEach( (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
  
        // find selected answer
        const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
        const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
        const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;
  
        // if answer is correct
        if(userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer){
          // add to the number of correct answers
          numCorrect++;
  
          // color the answers green
          answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = 'lightgreen';
        }
        // if answer is wrong or blank
        else{
          // color the answers red
          answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = 'red';
        }
      });
  
      // show number of correct answers out of total
      resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
    }
  
    function showSlide(n) {
      slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active-slide');
      slides[n].classList.add('active-slide');
      currentSlide = n;
      if(currentSlide === 0){
        previousButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
      else{
        previousButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      }
      if(currentSlide === slides.length-1){
        nextButton.style.display = 'none';
        submitButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      }
      else{
        nextButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
        submitButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  
    function showNextSlide() {
      showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    }
  
    function showPreviousSlide() {
      showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
    }
    
  
    // Variables
    const quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
    const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

    const myQuestions = [
      {
        answers: {
          a: "Titanic",
          b: "Love Actually",
          c: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind",
          d: "Moulin Rouge"
        },
        correctAnswer: "c"
      },
      {
        answers: {
          a: "Love, Simon",
          b: "Twilight",
          c: "The fall of our stars",
          d: "Not another teeanger movie"

        },
        correctAnswer: "c"
      },
      {
        answers: {
          a: "Amelie",
          b: "Contact",
          c: "Me before you",
          d: "50 first dates"
        },
        correctAnswer: "d"
      }
    ];
  
    // Kick things off
    buildQuiz();
  
    // Pagination
    const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    let currentSlide = 0;
  
    // Show the first slide
    showSlide(currentSlide);
  
    // Event listeners
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', showResults);
    previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
    nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
  })();
```

**All of my code is here:** [GITHUB Repository](https://github.com/alexcagira/WEB-CW) (So far I'm trying to make the romance quiz to work, and then I would implement it in all the others)

Answer (score 0):

I decided another approach:

```
var position = 0,
  quiz, quiz_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, correct = 0;

var questions = [
  { //Question 1
  a: "Love Actually",
  b: "Titanic",
  c: "Romeo + Juliet",
  d: "Moulin Rouge",
  answer: "d",
  img: "https://film-grab.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/moulinrouge062.jpg"
  },

  { //Question 2
    a: "The fall of our stars",
    b: "The Notebook",
    c: "Her",
    d: "Me before you",
    answer: "a",
    img: "https://variety.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/fault-in-our-stars.jpg"
  },

  { //Question 3
    a: "Call me by your name",
    b: "La La Land",
    c: "The curious case of Benjamin Button",
    d: "P.S. I love you",
    answer: "b",
    img: "https://film-grab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/lalal020.jpg"
  }];


function get(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

function renderQuestion() {
  quiz = get("quiz");
  if (position >= questions.length) {

    quiz.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";

    if(correct == 0){
      quiz.innerHTML += "<h2> YOU ARE AN AMATEUR </h2>";
    } //if ZERO questions are correct
  
    if(correct == 1){
      quiz.innerHTML += "<h2> YOU ARE AN CASUAL VIEWER </h2>";
    } //if ONE question is correct

    if(correct == 2){
      quiz.innerHTML += "<h2> YOU ARE AN AVERAGE VIEWER </h2>";
    } //if TWO questions are correct

    if(correct == 3){
      quiz.innerHTML += "<h2> YOU ARE A CINEMA LOVER </h2>";
    } //if THREE questions are correct

    get("quiz_status").innerHTML = "Quiz completed";
    //reset everything for the next quiz
    position = 0;
    correct = 0;

    quiz.innerHTML += "<button onclick='goHome()'>BACK HOME</button>";

    return false;
  }
  get("quiz_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (position + 1) + " of " + questions.length;

  question = questions[position].question;
  chA = questions[position].a;
  chB = questions[position].b;
  chC = questions[position].c;
  chD = questions[position].d;
  //Add local var to hold uri
  img = questions[position].img;

  quiz.innerHTML = "<h3></h3>";
  
  //Add <img> element to DOM with source
  quiz.innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + img + "\"><br>";

  quiz.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='a'> " + chA + "</label><be>";
  quiz.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='b'> " + chB + "</label><be>";
  quiz.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='c'> " + chC + "</label><be>";
  quiz.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='d'> " + chD + "</label><br><be>";
  quiz.innerHTML += "<button onclick='showPrevious()'>&#8678 Question</button>";
  quiz.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
  quiz.innerHTML += "<button onclick='showNext()'>Question &#8680</button>";
}

function checkAnswer() {
  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      choice = choices[i].value;
    }
  }

  if (choice == questions[position].answer) {
    correct++;
  }

  position++;

  renderQuestion();
}

//Show next question
function showNext() {
  position++;
  renderQuestion();
}
//Show previous question
function showPrevious() {
  position--;
  renderQuestion();
}

//Go back to the main page
function goHome(){
  document.location.href="/Users/alex/Desktop/Web Tech/WEB CW/quizselector.html";
}

window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion);
```